# Electron throwing error %1 is not a valid win32 application with custom node addon

Tags: node.js, electron

I've written a custom node addon that works perfectly fine when running the 64 bit version of Electron.
I tried setting the architecture to ia32 and everything builds, but I get the not valid win32 application error, no matter what I do.

My environment settings are:

```
npm_config_disturl=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell
set npm_config_target=1.0.1
set npm_config_arch=ia32
set npm_config_runtime=electron
set HOME="C:\Users\myHome\.electron-gyp"
set VCTargetsPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140
```

I have been building the addon by calling npm install.

Comment: Your node addon should use the same version as electron, ie, 64 bit.

Comment: I've installed 32 bit Electron, and tried building for 32 bit, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you try loading the addon through node in command line?

Comment: Fixed it.  As you said, I was running 64 bit node...*facepalm*  Thanks a ton, and sorry for being late on responding :)

Comment: I have the same problem. My step is:

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I set my node to target 32 bit and install all packages in 32bit format. It works for me. You may try.

```
npm set npm_config_arch ia32
npm clean-install --arch=ia32
```

The first command set the node environment to 32bit.
The second command re-install all the node packages that are 32bit compatible.

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to compile for windows from mi Mac and I had that problem too, but after some readings I figured out how to proceed, and after all I can say that I got it. Yesterday I spent all day setting up a windows virtual machine in my (other) Linux laptop (I used my linux laptop just because my mac was exhausted in storage...). I was having too a problem with the preloadScript from electron main process in windows, Cant found the script, it was solved too.

Anyway, I think the library node printer from @tojocky is well maintained, in other hand in the electron-builder documentation they say that you should compile in native for natural reasons. Once you will have it, you'll see that it's a cleaner and pragmatic solution ...

This was my entire process, I hope it helps to someone having the same issue:

- Get VirtualBox (or Parallels but is not free)
- Get iso for W10
- Create a VM with this W10 iso, and you should give to this VM some storage (because some dependency that you'll need to compile), I have assigned 60gb to this VM
- Once I had that VM running, I just installed in that machine Visual Studio 2017 (with their build-tools included, it's necessary)
- And then, I used CMD to make the rest
- Install NodeJS (and NPM, but it comes with)
- Install node-gyp globally
- Install Python 2.7
- Clone your project from git (in my case)
- npm i (in your project), you should have as npm dependency in your package.json the module electron-builder of course. (here I had some troubles because when node-gyp tried to rebuild printer to generate the binary for windows it was failing, this was because it was imposible to find the python executable, so if you face this problem you should add it like:npm config set python "c:\Python27\python.exe" in my case )

Then try again npm i and Voila!
After all, you should make the build using electron-builder, in my case my npm script command was build --win --x64 but you can use the --ia32 flag as well for 32bits